# org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss occur when I get zk's child Nodes

Tags: apache-zookeeper

the case as follow:
I call client.getChildren().forPath("/path".No problem under normal circumstances.

But if the childNodes is too many,the Exception:org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /path occured.

the code:

```
        RetryNTimes retryNTimes = new RetryNTimes(1, 1000);
        CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient("xx.xx.xx.xx:2181",
                50000, 50000, retryNTimes);
        client.start();
        List<String> childNodes = client.getChildren().forPath("/path");
```

the zkServer is three node cluster.the version is 3.4.13.

the curator version in my client is 2.12.0

someone do me a favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally,I find the source reason.the child nodes is too many.so the packet's length from server is  more than client packet's length limit(1024 * 4096).so I set the System properties -Djute.maxbuffer = 10485760.the problem is solved.

the relational code:

```
 public static final int packetLen = Integer.getInteger("jute.maxbuffer",
            4096 * 1024);

   protected void readLength() throws IOException {
        int len = incomingBuffer.getInt();
        if (len < 0 || len >= ClientCnxn.packetLen) {
            throw new IOException("Packet len" + len + " is out of range!");
        }
        incomingBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(len);
    }

        private void conLossPacket(Packet p) {
        if (p.replyHeader == null) {
            return;
        }
        switch (state) {
        case AUTH_FAILED:
            p.replyHeader.setErr(KeeperException.Code.AUTHFAILED.intValue());
            break;
        case CLOSED:
            p.replyHeader.setErr(KeeperException.Code.SESSIONEXPIRED.intValue());
            break;
        default:
            p.replyHeader.setErr(KeeperException.Code.CONNECTIONLOSS.intValue());
        }
        finishPacket(p);
    }
```

the logic as follow:

org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn.SendThread#run; ->  clientCnxnSocket.doTransport(to, pendingQueue, outgoingQueue, ClientCnxn.this); -> doIO(pendingQueue, outgoingQueue, cnxn); ->                    readLength(); -> cleanup(); -> conLossPacket(p)

the Exception:"org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /path" maybe mislead user.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer was very usefull ! Thanks, so much appreciated !

In my case, I got RangerKms not able to respond on it's endpoint and we have enabled a lot of debug mode inside many jars to get the errors below :

```
2024-02-11 10:14:02,270 WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x2000027d3af0874 for server <zkHost>:2181, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.io.IOException: Packet len4195723 is out of range!

 DEBUG org.apache.curator.RetryLoopImpl: Retrying operation
 DEBUG org.apache.curator.RetryLoopImpl: Retry-able exception received
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /zkdtsm/ZKDTSMRoot/ZKDTSMTokensRoot

 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[<kmsHost>].[/kms]: Exception starting filter [authFilter]
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not start class org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenManager$ZKSecretManager: java.io.IOException: Could not start PathChildrenCache for tokens

 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext: One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
 ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext: Context [/kms] startup failed due to previous errors
```

**Solution :**

Increase value of jute.maxbuffer to 100MB in ZooKeeper.
And appended the same (-Djute.maxbuffer=104857600) for the impacted service.

Hope one day this will help someone !